# Building a Panel-like Custom Control with Attached Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, attached-properties

I'm attempting to implement a WPF custom control that displays two collections of `FrameworkElement` objects in two separate panels.  The control derives from `ItemsControl` and has a `Canvas` which has `IsItemsHost="True"` set.  Additionally, I have a `Collection<FrameworkElement>` named `OtherItems` which I would like to display in a different `Canvas`.

The custom control defines an attached property: `myControl.Position` which determines the X position of the item within its canvas. The control also defines a `MinValue` and `MaxValue` dependency properties.  The control calculates uses the `MinValue`, `MaxValue` and `control.Position` properties to place the `UIElement`'s at the proper position:

`<----------0---------->` is the result of: MinValue=10, MaxValue=110, myControl.Position=60

I can handle positioning for items that are in the `myControl.Items` container, but items that are in `myControl.OtherItems` have a null `Parent` reference:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PositionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Position", typeof (double), typeof (myControl), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, OnPositionChanged));    

public static void OnPositionChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    var element = sender as FrameworkElement;
    if (element != null)
    {
        var container = element.Parent as myControl;
        if (container != null)
        {
            container.PositionElement(element);
        }
    }    
}  

<!--Within the myControl's template-->
<Canvas IsItemsHost="True" x:Name="PART_ItemCanvas"/>
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding OtherItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas x:Name="PART_OtherItemCanvas"/>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
 </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

<!-- As used -->
<custom:myControl MaxValue="1000" MinValue="-250">
    <custom:myControl.Items>
        <Button myControl.Position="0"/>
        <SomethingElse myControl.Position="25"/>
        <Etc myControl.Position="100"/>
   </custom:myControl.Items>
   <custom:myControl.OtherItems>
       <Button myControl.Position="20"/>
       <Label myControl.Position="300"/>
   </custom:myControl.OtherItems>
</custom:myControl>
```

How can I handle the call to `OnPositionChanged` when I do not have access to the sender's parents?  I'm assuming this is something that WPF layout controls do all the time, with attached properties like `Grid.Row` and `DockPanel.Dock`, but how do they manage it?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Edited it in.  Trying to figure out how attached properties used for layout are actually implemented.  Every resource on attached properties lists layout as a use-case, but never explains how, since the properties belong to the child, not the parent

Comment: You're overcomplicating this all way too much. Why don't you just use 2 different `ItemsControl`s?